# Flutter - ignore onTap in Child GestureDetector widgets of SingleChildScrollView while scrolling

Tags: flutter

I need to be able to scroll through a list of widgets without activating their onTap event when scrolling but be able to use the onTap when there is no scrolling taking place.

For example in this simplified version of my scenario I want to be able to scroll through the list of Text widgets here but not print out the text during the scroll, only print it out if there is no scrolling and the text widget is tapped:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print('Tap 1');
              },
              child: Text('Text 1')
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
               print('Tap 2');
              },
              child: Text('Text 2')
          ),

        .........

          GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print('Tap 100');
              },
              child: Text('Text 100')
          )
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Generally it ignores the on tap by default while scrolling

Comment: I'm seeing the onTap being actioned when starting the scroll, e.g. if I start the scroll by pressing Text 2 that onTap will be actioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code they provide should work just fine, scroll without activating their onTap, but if for some strange reason it still happens try using Listener.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isScrolling = false;

    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (_) => isScrolling = true,
      onPointerMove: (_) => isScrolling = true,
      onPointerUp: (_) => isScrolling = false,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: List.generate(
            20,
            (index) => GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("isScrolling $isScrolling");
                if (!isScrolling) {
                  print('Tap ${index + 1}');
                }
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('Texto ${index + 1}',
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```